# What realization for Repository<TEntity> for UnitOfWork factory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Good day,
I want to use UnitOfWork (Entity Framework) - Repositories - Application Services layers from [this example](https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2015/11/01/survey-of-entity-framework-unit-of-work-patterns/).
Application Service example:

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
  readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;
  readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory _unitOfWorkFactory;

  public CustomerService(IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory, ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
  {
    _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    _unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
  }

  public void CreateCustomer(CreateCustomerRequest request)
  {
    using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkFactory.Create())
    {
      try
      {
        customer = new Customer { FirstName = request.FirstName, LastName = request.LastName };
        _customerRepository.Add(customer);
        unitOfWork.Commit();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        unitOfWork.Rollback();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**How i can interract unitOfWork Context with Repository? How i can share Current context (by using UnitOfWork factory) in repositories (_customerRepository)? What about transaction?**

As DI container it's used AutoFac.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be looking for Repository pattern. As UOW is widely used with ADO.NET

Comment: If you like to implement Repository with Entity Framework and AutoFac *(not Unit of Work)*, you are feel free to browse my *small* project at [GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Libraries/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Services/Roles/RoleService.cs) and [AutoFac Register](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Infrastructure/DependencyManagement/DependencyRegistrar.cs#L49).

Comment: @Aravind, I know Repository pattern, i'm just dont understand how i implement `IUnitOfWorkFactory` and how it's interract with `ICustomerRepository`?

Comment: You should implement both ICustomerRepository , IUnitOfWorkFactory interfaces by your own classes. Then register them in AutoFac.

Comment: I think unitOfWork.Commit() should SaveDbChanges() in EntityFramework

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use both I suggest you to do something like this

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Commit();
    IDbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class;
}
```

Now your DBContext implement it:

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public void Commit()
    {
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
         //see below
        SetIsolationLevel();

        base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and for the Repositories, you only need to pass your DBContext

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : EntityBase
{
     protected DbContext Context;

     //this is the constructor for your base repositories
     public Repository(DbContext context)
     {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        Context = context;
    }

    public void Save(TEntity entity)
    {
        Save(entity);
    }

    public void Save(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) return;

        if (entity.Id == 0)
        {
            Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            //state is modified
            Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
        }
    }
```

However, your DI should only save the reference to each type in order to resolve them when you need it, it is your responsibility to know which type and parameters you inject.

Now for your transactions, depending the isolation level that you want to specify you can do something like this

```
        public MyDBContext (string connectionName)
            : base(connectionName)
        {

            Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            Database.CommandTimeout = 300;
            Database.Log = sql => Debug.WriteLine(sql);

            SetIsolationLevel("READ UNCOMMITTED");
        }

        private void SetIsolationLevel(string isolationLevel = null)
        {
            if (isolationLevel == null)
                isolationLevel = TransactionUtils.IsolationLevelString;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(isolationLevel))
            {
                Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL {isolationLevel};");
            }
        }
```

In any case I strongly recommend you to read this post to have another point of view when you want to use your unit of work and your repositories

http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/